# Check whether sentences contain certrain substrings

Tags: python

I have a data-frame that contains certain sentences, like for example this df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['how are you', 1], ['this is a random text', 1]], columns=('body', 'ticketID'))
list = df['body'].tolist()
```

Now I am looking for the most efficient way to check whether a string contains substrings (items in the list). So if we have this example

```
somestring1 = "this is a random text in a book"
somestring2 = "this text contains an error"
```

And the function should be

```
def getRidOfSentencePart():
   #//
```

getRidOfSentencePart(somestring1) should evaluatie to "in a book"
and getRidOfSentencePart(somestring1) should evaluatie to "this text contains an error"

Any thoughts on how I can program this most efficienctly?

Comment: SO is not a good site to ask "Any thoughts on how I can program this most efficienctly?". That makes your question opinion-based, which is a reason to close it. Additionally, it sounds like you are asking for free code that you don't want to take the trouble to write yourself, which will definitely not fly here.

Comment: You shouldn't name variables using Python built-in names, e.g. `list` or `set`... Try something like `my_list` or `arr` instead.

Comment: What have you tried? Why did it not work as expected? What errors did you see? Have you done any research on the question? (Hint: this is an extremely basic problem which is likely to have dozens similar answers on this site already)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for this, ahum,  nice and constructive feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "cut" all strings from the list you extracted from the dataframe from another given string you could just iterate over the list and replace with an empty string.

```
def getRidOfSentencePart(somestring):
    for i in dflist:
        somestring = somestring.replace(i, '')
    return somestring
```

If you want to trim spaces in the first and last position, you could instead `return somestring.strip()`. I cannot report much on efficiency of this approach though it does appear quite simple.